# How should I retrieve the other fields or data depending on what was selected by the user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I have this select component that takes the data from the firestore which was done in the parent component.

```
const SelectVaccine = ({ value, onChange, vaccines }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="vaccine">Vaccine Type</InputLabel>
        <Select value={value} onChange={onChange} fullWidth>
          {vaccines &&
            vaccines.map((index) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={index.vaccine}
                value={index.vaccine}
                // defaultValue={}
              >
                {index.vaccine}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectVaccine;
```

This is a document inside the vaccines collection:

[image]

I have this `SelectVaccine` component inside this parent form where the user can select what type of vaccine was administered. Depending on the vaccine that was selected especially for those with 2 dosages like AstraZeneca. There are days apart from the 1st and 2nd doses. I wanted to have an estimated date for the 2nd dose of the vaccine. How can I access the field `daysApart` from my firestore so I can add the `daysApart` to the date of the first dose of vaccine? Thank you.

I have this parent component with a form.

```
const Scan = ({ scanResult }) => {
  const [firstDose, setFirstDose] = useState(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
 
  //for the vaccines
  const [vaccines, setVaccines] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("vaccines")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) =>
          arr.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
          })
        );
        setVaccines(arr);
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const [selectedVaccine, setSelectedVaccine] = useState(0);
  const handleChangeVaccine = (e) => setSelectedVaccine(e.target.value);
  console.log(selectedVaccine);
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------

  //for the estimated 2nd Dose of vaccine------------------------------
  const date = new Date();
  var newdate = new Date(date);

  newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 28);

  var dd = newdate.getDate();
  var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = newdate.getFullYear();

  const secondDose = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
  const [secDose, setSecDose] = useState(secondDose); //variable for 2nd dose


  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        {isLoading ? (
          <>
            {users &&
              users.map((user) => (
                <li style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Grid container direction={"column"} spacing={2}>
                         <SelectVaccine
                      value={selectedVaccine}
                      onChange={handleChangeVaccine}
                      vaccines={vaccines}
                    />
                      <Grid item>
                    <TextField
                      type="text"
                      label="1st Dosage"
                      variant="outlined"
                      value={firstDose}
                      onChange={(e) => setFirstDose(e.target.value)}
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </Grid>
                     {selectedVaccine == "J&J" || selectedVaccine == "" ? (
                    <></>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <Grid item>
                        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                          <DatePicker
                            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                            value={secDose}
                            onChange={setSecDose}
                            fullWidth
                            id="date-picker-inline"
                            label="Estimated 2nd Dose of Vaccination"
                          />
                        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                      </Grid>
                    </>
                  )}
                      <Grid>
                        <ButtonForm type="submit" fullWidth>
                          Submit
                        </ButtonForm>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </form>
                </li>
              ))}
          </>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading...</h1>
        )}
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Scan;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedVaccine) {
    const { daysApart } = vaccines.find(vaccine => vaccine.vaccine === selectedVaccine);
    const doseDate = new Date();
    doseDate.setDate(doseDate.getDate() + daysApart);
    setSecDose(`${doseDate.getMonth() + 1}/${doseDate.getDate()}/${doseDate.getFullYear()}`);
  }
}, [selectedVaccine]);
```